# How should Ad splash pages be handled for those with ads disabled?

Tags: copywriting, advertisement

I see it all too often; I click a link to an article on the web and I get this:
[image]

It's not (as) readily apparent it's an ad screen, at first I thought it was the classic "white screen" of a page that failed to load. This greets a lot of us who use ad blocking add ons when browsing pages with these ad-splash screens.

Is there a better way to handle ad screens when the ad is removed? I've only ever seen one website "know" that you had removed it's ads in the past, [Newgrounds.com](http://newgrounds.com) displays a nagging message saying something to the effect of "hey, you blocked our ads! Buy something in our store instead to support us".

What can or should be done to compliment the experience of users disabling your ads. Perhaps even (professionally) goading them into enabling ads for that particular site, as newgrounds (fairly unprofessionally) does?

Comment: Well, if they can spot that their ads had been blocked, and they can display a message to the user, why not just display the ad? :) I mean, that's the whole point. If it's a matter of format (flash / banner blocked), then display an ad in a simpler format, that wouldn't be blocked.

Comment: Well it should be simple to just show some boilerplate text when the element on top of it (the ad) is cut out, actually displaying the ad is problematic because ad blockers usually go by domains (though ads hosted on-site are safer but can still be removed). Some simply copy saying like "hey, there should be ads here!" probably wouldn't be blocked so it could at least be used to show *something*...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two sites which handle ad-blocking in a way that enhances the user experience are [askmrrobot.com](http://askmrrobot.com) and [wowhead.com](http://wowhead.com). Not getting all bent out of shape seems to be key.

[image: robot apocalypse]
[image: wowhead]

Looking at the html source of these sites it can be seen they don't actually "know" you've blocked ads .. they've just absolute-positioned another div element in the same location underneath the ad being blocked.

Interestingly, wowhead.com also offers a facility to hide ads on [any page](http://wowhead.com/?search=exchange) you happen to be on. For users that don't have ad blockers this might well mitigate desire to get an ad blocker.

[image: hide ads]

Comment: This solution is almost exactly what I was thinking of, very interesting!