# How do interstitial ads impact site UX?

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, perception, advertisement, monetization

(Spawned by [How should Ad splash pages be handled for those with ads disabled?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12933/how-should-ad-splash-pages-be-handled-for-those-with-ads-disabled))

Has any data been published on the impact of interstitial (whole page ads between content) on the user's experience? Is my assumption that they're generally hated correct?

Comment: If you, and anyone you know hates Ads, then you must be correct. It is hard to like them. It is a fine balance between increasing revenue and keeping users on the site.

Comment: I don't know any studies, but I know I've personally left sites because the first and only thing I saw on them was a splash page ad, and I know I'm not alone.

Comment: Full screen ads with an ad blocker can lead to 'empty' pages. Always fun.

Comment: I don't think there are much studies that have scientifically proven that people don't like having the flu. However I guess we can safely assume that most people don't like having the flu. In the same manner I think we can assume that most people hate this kind of ads.

Comment: They impact UX by ruining it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Full page ads on the internet are hated**.  It's one of the more universal feelings on the internet.

I think the issue that you are looking at isn't whether people like them or whether they improve the UX.  Ads are used as a revenue source and a necessary evil for many sites.  So you need to effectively **do a cost benefit analysis** (or in this case revenue harm analysis).

No research is going to be able to tell you whether they are worth it for your application as each application and each audience is going to be very different.  You need to **do some A/B testing on your site and then look at the results** in order to decide if it is worth it for you.

I would however stress that ads like that are going to annoy many customers and others (like me) probably aren't even going to see them (AdBlock for Chrome rocks!).  So your revenue won't be universal to all customers but the annoyance will be.