# How to fit a MREC (Medium Rectangle ad) into a sidebar?

Tags: website-design, filter, space-constraints

I've seen some great sidebar designs (like filters for listing pages) and the list or grid to the right of it. My problem is that these seem to only be quite thin and fitting a 300px by 250px MREC advertising space is quite hard (to me) without making the rest of the website fit this in.

How would you work around such space constraints?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Can you please edit your post to clarify what MREC stands for? It [doesn't appear to be a very common acronym](http://www.acronymfinder.com/MREC.html).

Comment: Well, you could remove the ads... (I so wish that was a realistic option.)

Comment: It appears that MREC means a "medium rectangle" ad, sized 300x250.

Answer (score -1):

Try  an ad-before-load setup. So many sites do this, so it would be easy to assume it's OK. Fundamentally an ad-before-load setup is when you display a center-aligned ad before the page loads. A simple way to implement this is to make your links go to the regular sites, but add a script to redirect you to the ad site (Which you pass the URL as a URL variable), unless the URL contains a variable, (Let's say `&adViewed`), and then add a link to the site that you need to go to (Contained in the URL variable), plus the variable, so the page loads. This ensures that **1:** the ad is viewed, and **2:** The page remains uncluttered, and clean.

Comment: But this would be far more intrusive than a banner in a column next to the content. Relevant discussion: [How do interstitial ads impact site UX?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12944/how-do-interstitial-ads-impact-site-ux?rq=1)

Comment: Possibly. Still, a full-page ad looks MUCH better than a cluttered site with tons of ads down the side. Trust me, a user would much rather go through a 2s ad that covers the page than look at the eyesore of numerous down the front, top, and sides of the page.

Comment: @DripDrop I feel like comparing one single page ad to a page with numerous down the front, top, and sides is a bit of apples to oranges. Even this site shoves an 'ad' (it's normally an ad to other SE forums) on the sidebar, about the size OP is talking about too) and I would MUCH rather see that than a separate interstitial page.